# How to access a SpEL within a SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-el

I have an util map and and I’m trying to access map with key as a value from spring batch’s `jobParameters` using SpEL. Can’t get it work, can someone please help.

```
<util:map id=“abc”>
  <entry key=“12” value=“BMW”>
</util:map>

#{jobParameters[‘jobId’]} = 12
```

What I’m trying to do is get the value BMW from the util map using SpEL. This is what tried this and it’s not working `#{abc[#{jobParameters[‘jobId’]}]}`

Comment: What about `#{abc.get(jobParameters[‘jobId’])}` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `#{jobParameters[‘12’]}`

Comment: Beware of those smart quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
#{abc[jobParameters['jobId']]}
```